# Creating 360 degree spherical panoramas with Stitching Detailed Example

Tags: opencv, 360-panorama, opencv-stitching

I want to create spherical panorama image with
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp

I want to create image like generated by Panotools (www.panotools.org/dersch/).

Sample image,

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Facade_of_Birla_Auditorium,_A_360_Panorama-interactive_100_Pix_HDR-20130301.JPG

Does this example support this functionality ? If yes, how ?